# Handle stream of data sensor

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-sensors

I'm trying to write a code I can write all the results values from accelerometer sensor into a .txt file. I can't write all the data in somehow. I think there is a problem in my loop. It is just reading about 10 to 15 samples. 
How can I write all the values of the sensor into that file until I toggle off the button to stop? here is the code I wrote.
Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
public SensorManager sm;
Sensor accelermeter;

private static final String DEBUG = "LogAccelermeter";
ToggleButton OnStore;
Button OffStore;
Button btnOn, btnOff;
TextView txtArduino, txtString, txtStringLength, sensorView0, sensorView1, sensorView2, sensorView3;
Handler bluetoothIn;

final int handlerState = 0;                         //used to identify handler message
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();

private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

// SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
TextView sensorText;
// String for MAC address
private static String address;
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

double TotalAccelerate;
ArrayList<Double> list;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = new ArrayList<Double>();

     //Link the buttons and textViews to respective views
    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
    btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
    txtString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtString);
    txtStringLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView1);
    sensorView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView0);
    sensorView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView1);
    sensorView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView2);
    sensorView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView3);

    //for Accelermeter
    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensor);
    accelermeter = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this, accelermeter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());


    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File Root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        File file = new File(dir, "MyMessage.txt");
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SDcard not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    OnStore = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.onStore);
    OnStore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (OnStore.isChecked()){
                try {
                    for(double TotalAccelerate : list){
                     //   System.out.println("final"+ TotalAccelerate);
                        String space = "\n";
                        byte[] convert = space.getBytes();
                        fileOutputStream.write(convert);
                        String finalData;
                        finalData = String.valueOf(TotalAccelerate);
                        fileOutputStream.write(finalData.getBytes());
                        Log.i(DEBUG, "ans: " + finalData);
                    }
                    // fileOutputStream.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }if (!OnStore.isChecked()){
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    list.clear();
                    Collections.synchronizedList(list);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message Stopped.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }

    });


    bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                        //if message is what we want
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                        // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                recDataString.append(readMessage);                                    //keep appending to string until ~
                int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                    String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                    txtString.setText("Data Received = " + dataInPrint);
                    int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();                            //get length of data received
                    txtStringLength.setText("String Length = " + String.valueOf(dataLength));

                    if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')    //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                    {
                        String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 5);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                        String sensor1 = recDataString.substring(6, 10);            //same again...
                        String sensor2 = recDataString.substring(11, 15);
                        String sensor3 = recDataString.substring(16, 20);

                        sensorView0.setText(" Sensor 0 Voltage = " + sensor0 + "V");    //update the textviews with sensor values
                        sensorView1.setText(" Sensor 1 Voltage = " + sensor1 + "V");
                        sensorView2.setText(" Sensor 2 Voltage = " + sensor2 + "V");
                        sensorView3.setText(" Sensor 3 Voltage = " + sensor3 + "V");
                    }
                    recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
                    // strIncom =" ";
                    dataInPrint = " ";
                }
            }
        }
    };

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
    checkBTState();

    // Set up onClick listeners for buttons to send 1 or 0 to turn on/off LED
    btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mConnectedThread.write("0");    // Send "0" via Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mConnectedThread.write("1");    // Send "1" via Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}//end OnCreate Method

@Override
public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
}

@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // The light sensor returns a single value.
    // Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.
    double xx = event.values[0];
    double yy = event.values[1];
    double zz = event.values[2];
    TotalAccelerate = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
            + Math.pow(yy, 2)
            + Math.pow(zz, 2)));
    Log.i(DEBUG, "Accelerometer = " + TotalAccelerate);

    list.add(TotalAccelerate);
    findPeaks(list);
   sensorText.setText("Total: " + TotalAccelerate);
    Log.i(DEBUG, "list values " + list);

}

//Find peak values.
public static ArrayList<Double> findPeaks(List<Double> points) {
    ArrayList<Double> peaks = new ArrayList<Double>();

    if (points == null || points.size() < 1)
        return peaks;

    Double x1_n_ref = 0.0;
    int alpha = 0; //0=down, 1=up.
    int size = points.size();// -1)/100;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 5) {
        Double IndexValues = points.get(i);
        if (IndexValues > 9) {
            Double delta = (x1_n_ref - IndexValues);
            if (delta < 0) {
                x1_n_ref = IndexValues;
                alpha = 1;

            } else if (alpha == 1 && delta > 0) {
                peaks.add(x1_n_ref);

                alpha = 0;
            }

        } else if (alpha == 0) {
            x1_n_ref = IndexValues;
        }
    }

    return peaks;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDown: " + event.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "OnDown Touch Occur", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (event.getX() > 0) {
            mConnectedThread.write("1");
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString());
        mConnectedThread.write("0");

    }

private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

    return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
    //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Get MAC address from DeviceListActivity via intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //Get the MAC address from the DeviceListActivty via EXTRA
    address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

    //create device and set the MAC address
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            //insert code to deal with this
        }
    }
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
    //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
    mConnectedThread.write("x");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        //Don't leave Bluetooth sockets open when leaving activity
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        //insert code to deal with this
    }
}

//Checks that the Android device Bluetooth is available and prompts to be turned on if off
private void checkBTState() {

    if (btAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}

//create new class for connect thread
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    //creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            //Create I/O streams for connection
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytes;

        // Keep looping to listen for received messages
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //write method
    public void write(String input) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if you cannot write, close the application
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please include your enclosing class definition? This code snippet is not showing what interface or base class you are using. And also what's the time interval between you toggling on/off the button? As you are using **SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL**, it might not generate as many data points as you imagined.

Comment: Okay, I **update** the code based on your request. The Bluetooth code part doesn't related. I don't think it matters

Comment: Could you switch ```if (OnStore.isChecked())``` to ```if (!OnStore.isChecked())```, and ```if (!OnStore.isChecked())``` to ```if (OnStore.isChecked())``` see if that works.

Comment: I did switched. I got an empty .txt file. I also changed sensor delay, it makes the sensor reading very fast only. The problem is in the**for loop at OnStore.isChecked** I assume.

Comment: I guess that's possible as when you are in this loop, the *onAccuracyChanged* callback could fire and adding new items in the list, which is a potential racing condition. Did you try to stop listening to the sensor, before you iterate through the list?

Comment: No, really, I'm still intermediate level in android. Could you provide a pseudo code please.

Comment: It is actually stop writing into the file  before attempting to stop manually by the ToggleButton

Comment: I think the problem might still be in the the toggle state. Could you try the code I posted in the answer? It's not handling the accessing of the same list at two different places, but it should show you all the data in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this for the toggle button onClick callback? It should write all the data when it's unchecked.

```
OnStore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (OnStore.isChecked()){
            // should do nothing
        } else if (!OnStore.isChecked()){
            try {
                for(double TotalAccelerate : list){
                    //System.out.println("final"+ TotalAccelerate);
                    String space = "\n";
                    byte[] convert = space.getBytes();
                    fileOutputStream.write(convert);
                    String finalData;
                    finalData = String.valueOf(TotalAccelerate);
                    fileOutputStream.write(finalData.getBytes());
                    Log.i(DEBUG, "ans: " + finalData);
                }
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message Stopped.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

To regulate the code to start/stop listen to the sensor event, add the following variable somewhere in this class:

```
private boolean isListening = false;
```

And make the following modifications to your existing code:

```
OnStore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (OnStore.isChecked()){
            //
            // set listening flag to true
            //
            isListening = true;
        } else if (!OnStore.isChecked()){
            //
            // set listening flag to false
            //
            isListening = false;
            try {
                for(double TotalAccelerate : list){
                    //System.out.println("final"+ TotalAccelerate);
                    String space = "\n";
                    byte[] convert = space.getBytes();
                    fileOutputStream.write(convert);
                    String finalData;
                    finalData = String.valueOf(TotalAccelerate);
                    fileOutputStream.write(finalData.getBytes());
                    Log.i(DEBUG, "ans: " + finalData);
                }
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Message Stopped.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});


@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // The light sensor returns a single value.
    // Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.
    //
    // regulate
    //
    if (isListening) {
        double xx = event.values[0];
        double yy = event.values[1];
        double zz = event.values[2];
        TotalAccelerate = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
            + Math.pow(yy, 2)
            + Math.pow(zz, 2)));
        Log.i(DEBUG, "Accelerometer = " + TotalAccelerate);

        list.add(TotalAccelerate);
        findPeaks(list);
        sensorText.setText("Total: " + TotalAccelerate);
        Log.i(DEBUG, "list values " + list);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! I don't have enough points to make discussion here. they will block me. But magically it works. How can I approve the code do you think?

Comment: No worries, someone else will flag it as answer. I will also add the code you need to start/stop adding sensor data to your list later.

Comment: I truly thank you. I don't know how can I find you later, but anyway, thanks a lot. Best wishes.

Comment: so basically your code implemented takes whatever inside the list and write it into the file after I toggle off. Am I correct?